# How come I can login with Steam and Launch Pad

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, openid

I am sorry if I should ask this some where else but I was wondering why can I login with Steam on Gaming.SE and Launch Pad on Ask Ubuntu.

I don't mind them being on site-by-site design but it would be good if that could be on all sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can in fact log in with those providers anywhere, you just need to type in the OpenID URL.

The buttons are simply shortcuts to manually typing in the OpenID URL of the specific provider.

Comment: Could you please add an link for it on all sites.